# route main site traffic from non-www to www while keeping sub domains alive with nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, nginx, domain-name-system

The desired functionality of my nginx configuration for my website is as follows.

1. All main site traffic to `example.com` should redirect to `https://www.example.com`. All `non-www` traffic to the base domain should be re-written to be `www`.
2. All existing subdomains need to be kept alive for my enterprise clients and routed to https (e.g. `nike.example.com` to `https://nike.example.com`)

In my current configuration below the only case that does not work is when I type `https://example.com` into my browser, the browser shows me the *Your connection is not private page* indicating the site is not safe. I understand that the configuration below does not cover this case but I don't know how to solve the problem without killing off all the subdomains.

How can I alter this configuration file to cover all the cases above?

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  listen [::]:80 default_server; 
  root /var/www/website;
  index index.html;
  server_name www.example.com;
  server_tokens off;

  if ($http_x_forward_proto = 'http') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
  } 

  location / {
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html =404; 
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup additional virtual host, serving just example.com, ie:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name example.com;
     return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

also, if you want to have redirection using tls (https), then you will have to setup virtual host and have certificate that covers example.com and www.example.com domains.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response -  I have a wildcard SSL certificate for all `*.example.com` subdomains that are applied to a load balancer upstream. I will try adding this virtual host block above the existing configuration and test.

Comment: Afaik *.example.com certificate does not cover example.com

Comment: With your advice, I added another server block as seen above. Also, with AWS ACM, I was able to associate example.com's and *example.com's certificates to the same load balancer. Thank you.